# How is Optimus Prime in the movieverse a prime

Tags: transformers, optimus-prime

If he destroyed the matrix in the Revenge of the Fallen how is he a prime?

I thought all primes had the matrix?

Comment: "The Optimus formerly known as Prime"?

Answer (score 2):

First of all there is some misconception it seems. There is only ONE single matrix we know of in the filmverse (and also in almost all other universes).

Secondly even though the matrix dissolved to bring prime back to life....it reappeared in Transformers 3 where it was inside of his chest.

Now as to HOW he is a prime with / without the matrix is a bit more complicated. As it changed considerably during the years how this is handled. At first it was the one who held the matrix was "Prime". Nowadays it is that you are either one of the first primes, or (like mentioned in Revenge of the Fallen) you have a prime as an ancestor.

Although I have to admit the last thing I never understood how that is possible as......Transformers are created not exactly born. Maybe the new film will shed some light into that (Transformers 5), but I don't have much hope there though as it was mentioned only in Transformers 2 and never again (with the ancestors).

(So even while Optimus did not have the Matrix...in the universe he was still a prime. Same for Sentinel PRIME).

Comment: To make things even more complicated, there were TWO different matrixes(?) in the original canon. One was the "Matrix of Leadership", which is the orb stored in Optimus Prime's chest, and which contains the combined power & wisdom of the previous Primes. The other is a program (not a physical device) called the "Matrix of Creation", and it was what allowed someone to bring a new Transformer to life.

Comment: Although the so called Matrix of creation was a program within Vector sigma if I remember it correctly. In some transformerverses Vector Sigma is in reality Primus.   If one talks about the matrix though it is almost always about the matrix of leadership in the transformersverse (the matrix of cration seemingly got forgotten again by the creators of the series as I can only remember it being mentioned in one or two episodes at all). .

Comment: same thing happened in the Marvel comics. They even had a couple of story arcs where the Decepticons had to steal the Matrix of Creation from Prime's brain before they could create more Decepticons. Shockwave kidnapped Prime in order to bring the Constructicons to life, and the program accidentally got loaded into Buster Witwicky's brain. That was fun times. Eventually, though, they retconned it so that the Creation Matrix program was stored INSIDE the Matrix of Leadership, which was apparently discovered only after they launched Optimus Prime's corpse into space.